# Criar leitura de uma função bool em lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Bem estou aprendendo lua e estou com uma dúvida, estou tentando criar a leitura de uma função bool em lua.

Eu tenho uma função que desativa ou ativa conforme eu marcar true ou false.

Essa função se chama `useappenabled` só que não estou conseguindo aplicar ela em lua, antes eu usava no formato de libconf e funcionava normalmente antes era escrita da seguinte forma.

No lua está da seguinte forma a função:

```
Enableapp = 
{
    Useapp = true;
};
```

Agora a leitura antes em formato de libconfig era a seguinte, observem que a função useappenabled é aplicada o valor de entrada, ou seja true ou false se eu colocar no Useapp

```
if (config_lookup(&onf, "Enableapp"))
        if (config_setting_lookup_bool(cf, "Useapp", &SelectValue))
            useappenabled = SelectValue;
```

Então eu tentei mudar o código de libconfig para lua, porém não estou conseguindo fazer a leitura da função `useappenabled` , o código está da seguinte forma no lua

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Enableapp");
    lua_pushstring(L, "Useapp");
    lua_tonumber(L, useappenabled);
```

Creio eu que o problema seja lua_tonumber, eu precisaria de fazer algo mais ou menos como isso:

```
useappenabled = value_de_Useapp;
```

Porém estou começando agora, alguém sabe me dizer como posso aplicar a função `useappenabled` para ser igual o valor de `Useapp`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lua_getfield` para pegar o valor de um campo de uma tabela:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Enableapp");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Useapp");
useappenabled = lua_toboolean(L,-1);
```

Note a conversão com `lua_toboolean` e não com `lua_tonumber`.